# jQuery show/hide div dont works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, show-hide

I'm a novice in jQuery. I have a **a.acessaPonto** if I click it, add/remove class **a.acessaPonto.Selected**  and show/hide a **div.AcessaPontoAtendimento**. I have code like that. Works well in Firefox and IE but doesn't work in Chrome.

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.acessaPonto').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('Selected');
  if ($(this).hasClass('Selected'))
        $('.AcessaPontoAtendimento').css("display", "inline-block");
  else
  $('.AcessaPontoAtendimento').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
```

```css
.acessaPonto{
  background-color:blue;
}
.acessaPonto.Selected{
  background-color:red;
}

.AcessaPontoAtendimento{
  display:none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="acessaPonto">Click</a>
  <div class="AcessaPontoAtendimento">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor color</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Someone have a idea what's the problem in my code?

Comment: can you include the html relevant to the jquery? Also it might be easier to have the display set separately in the css

Comment: What doesn’t work? Is there any error message shown in Chrome’s console?

Comment: Can you include the css and html page

Comment: You didn't describe the problem well. I believe it is about navigating away on click, which you don't want. If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code works fine. The real problem is in my chrome. I kill app and reopen again and well, the code Works!**

But I ajust some parts to works better with old code in application.

```
$('.acessaPonto').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('Selected');
    if ($(this).hasClass('Selected'))
    $('.AcessaPontoAtendimento').removeClass('hide'); // maybe you prefer .show();
    else
    $('.AcessaPontoAtendimento').addClass('hide'); // maybe you prefer .hide();
});
```

Tnx all for the support.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.acessaPonto').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('Selected');
    $('.AcessaPontoAtendimento').toggle( $(this).hasClass('Selected') );
});
```

In case your `.acessaPonto` is on an `a` tag, you need `e.preventDefault()`, otherwise not.